# real infinitesimal weights in Representations Of Compact Lie Groups.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, lie-derivative

I'm currently reading *Representations Of Compact Lie Groups* by T. Bröcker and T. Tom Dieck. In the section to *Representations and Lie Algebras* (p.112) they introduce the notion of (infinitesimal) weights of a (complex) $T$-module $V$, where $T$ is a maximal torus and $V$ a euclidian vector space. They define a **weight** of $V$ as follows:

> A homomorphism $\vartheta\colon T\to U(1)$ is called a weight of $V$
> if the corresponding weight space $$V(\vartheta) = \{v\in V\mid xv =
>  \vartheta(x)\cdot v\  \text{for all}\ X\in \mathrm{L}T\}$$ is nonzero.

In Notation (9.7) they state ($L_X$ refers to the Lie-derivative at $X$):

> An $\mathbb{R}$-linear form $\alpha\colon \mathrm{L}T\to \mathbb{R}$
> is a **real** (infinitesimal) weight of the $T$-module $V$ if $2\pi i
>  \alpha$ is an infinitesimal weight of $V$. The weight space of $\alpha$ is then $$V(\alpha) = \{v\in V\mid \mathrm{L}_Xv = 2\pi i \alpha(X)\cdot v\
>  \text{for all}\ X\in \mathrm{L}T\}.$$

For clarification, i provide the definition of an infinitesimal weight as in Definition 9.3 on p.112:

> An $\mathbb{R}$-linear form $\Theta\colon \mathrm{L}T \to
>  \operatorname{LU}(1) = i\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is called an
> infinitesimal weight of the $T$-module $V$ if the corresponding weight
> space $$V(\Theta) = \{v\in V\mid \mathrm{L}_Xv = \Theta(X)\cdot v\
>  \text{for all}\ X\in \mathrm{L}T\}$$ is nonzero.

**My question:** What is meant by

> if $2\pi i\alpha$ is an infinitesimal weight of $V$

?

According to the definitions, an infinitesimal weight of $V$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear form $\mathrm{L}T \to\operatorname{LU}(1)$. So what is meant by saying that $2\pi i\alpha$ is an infinitesimal weight of $V$?

Thanks for any help!